# add serial number column in datatable pdf export

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am working on e-commercial project using html and javascript in my project. As a part I need to show the details of product ordered. I am using Jquery datatable inorder show the details. I need to export the details from datatable to excel and using. this all works fine but the problem is I need to add serial number while exporting I tried several ways. Below is the export buttons

```
buttons: [
        {
          extend: "excel",
          footer: true,
          title: "my report",
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
          },
        },
        {
          extend: "pdf",
          footer: true,
          title: "my report",
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
          },
        },
      ]
```

I added my zero th column along with the pdf export. but this fails while export the pdf after filtering

please help me to solve this huddle? if any clarity need please comment I will do my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your can custom fields in datatable on export to pdf or excel through below code.

```
buttons: [
        {
          extend: "excel",
          footer: true,
          title: "my report",
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
          },
        },
        {
          extend: "pdf",
          footer: true,
          title: "my report",
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [1, 2, 3, 4],
          },
          customize: function (doc) {
            var col = doc.content[1].table.body;
            for (i = 1; i < col.length; i++) {
              col[i][0]["text"] = i;
            }
          },
        },
      ]
```